# Laravel 5 Changing Environment to match URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed a fresh copy of Laravel.

I need it so i can set the environment to the URL.

So for instance in L4 i used this within the `start.php` file

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '';
});
```

This then loaded the correct environment for the project, so if we had a local domain `dev.laravel.com` it would load in the environment variables from `dev.laravel.com`

I cannot do this within Laravel 5.

Any guesses how I can apply this?

Comment: Please read the doc http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example do it for use different database, then you have some different variables on .env like:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=foo
DB_PASSWORD=foo

DB_HOST_2=localhost
DB_DATABASE_2=database2
DB_USERNAME_2=foo
DB_PASSWORD_2=foo
```

and in config/dababase.php:

```
'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_2', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

and finally use:

```
Config::set('database.default', "mysql") or Config::set('database.default', "mysql2")
```

depending you need.

For example I use to change database connection after login user doing it at controller abstract class changing the value depending session var, that is changed after login depending type of user:

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

    use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        Config::set('database.default', Session::get('myapp.database','mysql'));
    }
}
```

After login I put to change this value:

```
Session::set('myapp.database', 'mysql2') or Session::set('myapp.database', 'mysql')
```

and in the next call to  controller the database connections is changed.

Comment: Could we do this for multiple environment files? as i use a staging server and i want to be able to push the environment out without having to manually deploy .env file before it starts working.

Comment: You can try to implement for example a config parameter to select the configuration depending the hostname or url. But if you have different servers you should use .env on every server with their configuration. But is the same server with different urls you can try this.

Comment: Gave this a go and it works amazingly. Thanks. Now I don't have to deploy configurations for each server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `.env` file in each of your environments - and put the specific config for those environments into the `.env` file

So one one environment you might put

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

and in another `.env` on a different environment you might put

```
APP_ENV=staging
APP_DEBUG=false
DB_PASSWORD=other
```

Comment: what do you mean by different environment? I want to load diff .env files depending on the production or local environment. How would I do that?

Comment: so in your production server you have a `.env` file - and on your local server you have a different `.env` file